# Issue on Ordering Raphaël Drawing on Top of Other Divs

Tags: html, css, raphael, z-index

Using Raphaël—JavaScript Library at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/EN5Pf/) I am trying to draw on the top of Two divs (**#layer1 and #layer2**) which they have image background. But As you can see the drawing object (Red Circle) is sitting at the back of other images (The reason of that is visible is using PNG image for layers).

Can you please let me know how I can reorder them and change the zindex of the elements to ring the drawing object to the first on the top?

```
#layer1 {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:794px;
    height:680px;
    background-image: url('http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/che2_zps88cdd50e.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
}
#layer2 {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:794px;
    height:680px;
    background-image: url('http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/che_zps3fa0eafd.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:10;
}
#canvas {
    z-index:500;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of bits to possibly change... fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EN5Pf/2/)

For the z-index to take effect, you need to add

```
position: absolute;
```

to the css for that element;

I've also put the background-color onto the first divs style, so it doesn't hide the other picture, or you could possibly add opacity to that or something instead.